# recursive function breaking in if statement javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, recursion

i'm in the process of trying to write a function that converts an amount into a specified number of coins. For this I'm calling a function on itself (I think this is recursive programming?). I'm having 2 problems.

1. When i call the function on itself in the `else` section of the `if` statement I get the error message. "Maximum call stack size exceeded" ? Not sure why this is as the call above is the same and works fine when this second call is commented out.
2. Also when the second call is commented out and the function runs the variable `total` should be increasing by 1 with each call. However it doesn't make it past 1. I thought this may be because the variable was being reset at the top to 0 with each call. However the `remainder` variable is also set to 0 decreases its value each time.

Can anyone explain what is happening here ? How is this problem best solved ?

Thanks

```
function amountCoins(amt, coins) {

var remainder = 0;
total = 0;

if(amt >= coins[0]) {
    total += 1;
    remainder = (amt - coins[0]); 
    return amountCoins(remainder, coins);
} else {
    coins.shift();
    //return amountCoins(remainder,coins);

}
alert(total);
}

amountCoins(121,[20,15,6,1]);
```

Comment: You must have a non-recursive return, where the call chain can end. If you don't have one, the function will call itself infinitely and fills up the stack. That's why you get "Maximum call stack size exceeded". A good exit point could be when the coins array is empty, in this case you should return total.

Comment: The function should return the minimum number of the total coins that will be needed to make the specified amount

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reduce()` for this as an alternative.

And we don't really need loops where simple math can handle it.

```
var total = [20,15,6,1].reduce(function(obj, denomination) {
    return {
        total: obj.total + Math.floor(obj.amount / denomination),
        amount: obj.amount % denomination
    };
}, {amount:121, total:0}).total;
```

---

Or iterate the array.

```
var arr = [20,15,6,1], amount = 121, total = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    total += Math.floor(amount / arr[i]);
    amount %= arr[i];
}
```

Comment: Excellent use of reduce

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a regular `for` loop instead, if I was you:

```
var amt = 121;
var coins = [20, 15, 6, 1];

var coinsUsed = {};
var totalCoins = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
    if (coins[i] <= amt) {
        coinsUsed[coins[i]] = Math.floor(amt / coins[i]);
        amt -= coinsUsed[coins[i]] * coins[i];
        totalCoins += coinsUsed[coins[i]];
    } else {
        coinsUsed[coins[i]] = 0;
    }
}

console.log(coinsUsed, totalCoins);
```

Output:

```
Object {
    1: 1, 
    6: 0, 
    15: 0, 
    20: 6
}

7
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your algorithm *never ends*. Every recursive function must have an end, if not it will produce a **stack overflow** (xD), because recursive calls are stored in a stack.

This would be a solution:

```
function amountCoins(amt, coins, total) {    
    var remainder = 0;
    total = total || 0;   //Default value 0 (for the first call)    
    if(coins.length == 0) return total;   //This is the ending condition (no coins)
    if(amt >= coins[0]) {
       total += 1;
       remainder = (amt - coins[0]); 
       return amountCoins(remainder, coins, total);
    } else {
       coins.shift();
       return amountCoins(remainder, coins, total);
    }   
}
var coins = amountCoins(121,[20,15,6,1]);  //Returns: 6
alert(coins);
```

As you can see, I turned `total` into a param so we can store it from call to call.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Would I be right in thinking that to keep the value of a variable in recursion is to use it in the parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are trying to do:

```
function amountCoins(amt, coins) {
  var remainder = 0;        
  if(coins.length == 0) {
    return 0;
  } else if(amt >= coins[0]) {
      remainder = (amt - coins[0]); 
      return amountCoins(remainder, coins)+1;
  } else {
      coins.shift();
      return amountCoins(remainder,coins);    
  }
}

var total = amountCoins(121,[20,15,6,1]);
alert(total)
```

There are a few things here

1. A recursive algorithm needs a terminating condition. ie. when the function is calling itself recursively it should stop the chain at some point. If it doesnt, the program will run out of memory to accomodate all the calls in the chain. Because this is a potentially dangerous condition, programming languages like javascript limit the depth of a recursive call. This is what is meant by the `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

   In your program, logically, the terminating condition is when we run out of coins. so a 
   `coins.length == 0` check that returns a `0` total (which in turn seeds the upward chain) will fix the problem
2. Usually in recursive algorithms the result is passed backwards, up the call chain and not stored in an external variable. So the incrementing total value is expressed with a return statement like `return amountCoins(remainder, coins)+1;`

Finally, this problem can be much easily implemented with for loops. Try to think by unwinding the recursive call chains and you'll figure out a loop solution.

Answer (score 0):

This correction to your original code will work:

```
function amountCoins(amt, coins, total) {

    total = total || 0; 
    if (amt === 0) return total;

    // throw out all the coins that are too big
    while (amt < coins[0]) coins.shift(); 

    // use the largest coin possible, then recurse
    total += 1;
    remainder = amt - coins[0]; 
    return amountCoins(remainder, coins, total);
}

alert(amountCoins(121,[20,15,6,1])); // alerts 7
```

It has the advantage of avoiding unnecessary `if ... else` statements, and the logic is bit clearer imo

Answer (score 0):

You must return total not only if no coins left, but also if the last coin's value is bigger then the remaining value:

```
function amountCoins(amt, coins, total) {

    total = total || 0;

    if (coins.length == 0 || (amt < coins[0] && coins.length == 1)) return total;

    if (amt >= coins[0]) {
        total += 1;
        remainder = (amt - coins[0]); 
        return amountCoins(amt - coins[0], coins, total);
    } else {
        coins.shift();
        return amountCoins(remainder, coins, total);
    }
}
```